# Orthogonal Trajectories of a Circle

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the orthogonal trajectories of the family of circles centered at (1, 1). What shape are the orthogonal trajectories?

$(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2=c$

$2+2dy/dx = 0$

$y=-x+c$

$y= -x+(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2$

What am I doing wrong? Im assuming the solutions are straight lines. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks,

Comment: the derivative of $(x-1)^2$ is $2(x-1)$. Similar comments apply to the other term.

Comment: Some step by step with examples - http://www.sosmath.com/diffeq/first/orthogonal/orthogonal.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What shape are the tangential trajectories to the curve? They follow the tangents to the curve, which you get by implicit differentiation:
$$
(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2=c\Rightarrow 2(x-1)+2(y-1)\frac{dy}{dx}=0\Rightarrow \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x-1}{1-y}
$$
Then using that the orthogonal trajectories are orthogonal to the tangential trajectories, take the negative reciprocal and solve the separable ode:
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y-1}{x-1}\Rightarrow \frac{dy}{y-1}=\frac{dx}{x-1}\Rightarrow
y=A(x-1)+1
$$
Now we use the condition that the trajectories must lie on the curve to find the value of A in terms of the parameter for your family of curves, namely at that at $x=0$ $y=\pm\sqrt{c}+1$ yielding 
$$
\pm\sqrt{c}+1=A(-1)+1\Rightarrow \pm\sqrt{c}=-A
$$

Comment: I do not understand how you found the result of $y = A(x-1) + 1$ When I solve I get $(y-1) = x-1 + c$

Comment: @njo I just solved the new ode

Comment: disregard I figured it out

Answer (score 0):

$${d\over dx}\left\{(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2 \right\}=2(x-1)\cdot 1+2(y-1)\cdot{d(y-1)\over dx}\\=2(x-1)\cdot 1+2(y-1)\cdot{dy\over dx}$$

Now proceed

Comment: $$(-2x+2)dx=(2y-2)dy$$ therefore$$y^2-2y=-x^2-2x+c$$   so we substitute $$(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2=c$$ ?

Comment: Do you know how to find orthogonal trajectories? Replacing ${dy\over dx}$ by ${dx\over dy}$....

Comment: @Qwerty I think you forgot a minus sign. Btw love the name.

Comment: My mistake. So $$(2y-2/2x-2)=dy/dx$$ $$1/2ln(2x-2)=1/2ln(2y-2)+c$$

Comment: @qbert yup .. Sorry for the typo.. One should replace ${dy\over dx}$ by $-{dx\over dy}$.

Comment: @qbert Thanks for the compliment..:-)

Comment: @njo Please dont leave answers unaccepted(or unupvoted) . This is a bad habit already inculcated by more that $50\%$ of the members here!